# Proper way to call a WCF service using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, wcf, url

I have no idea of the URL to use for a call to WCF service method using jQuery. I'm new to WCF.

```
url:'http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/RnDServiceLibrary/Service1/mex/SetJSON',
```

The above is not working.

Comment: what error are you getting can you post that using firebug console or developer tools error console 
is it 404 error

Comment: "NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/RnDServiceLibrary/Service1/mex/SetJSON?undefined=undefined&undefined=undefined&undefined=undefined&undefined=undefined&undefined=undefined&undefined=undefined&undefined=undefined&undefined=undefined&undefined=undefined&undefined=undefined"

Comment: @ Darshana check this post and see selected answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323551/http-bad-request-error-when-requesting-a-wcf-service-contract  and also try browsing your wcf service in browser directly using this path and check if it's there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first host the wcf service in localhost and then I use this url `http://localhost:81/Test/Service.svc/MethodName?parameterName=" + "{ \"pl\":" + mylist + " }"`

Answer (score 2):

Use service url/method where method is used in service. 
Url="http://localhost:52136/Service1.svc/GetCustomer"; where GetCustomer is method that is created you in you wcf service.

Please Check this link also 
[Wcf Service Jquery](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/223572/Calling-Cross-Domain-WCF-service-using-Jquery-Java)